# How to disable mod_pagespeed without having to reboot server?

Tags: centos7, mod-pagespeed

I have a centos 7 with mod_pagespeed installed, and whenever I want to disable mod_pagespeed momentarily I go to /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/etc/httpd/conf.d/pagespeed.conf and set below line to off

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    ModPagespeed off
```

What happens is that it won't take effect at all. Pages will still be shown cached until I reboot the server.

Is there a way to not reboot?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just restart only the web server.

```
service httpd restart
```

(or whatever method does that in your cleary non-standard web server install)